# HTML5 app with Appcelerator Titanium

Tags: html, titanium, appcelerator

I am an Acquisition Editor for IT books. I am thinking of developing a book on developing HTML5 apps with Appcelerator Titanium. Does it make sense to have a book dedicated to developing HTML5 apps? if yes, what would you like to see in the book?

Comment: You can't develop HTML5 apps with Titanium. It will convert everything to native platform code, so they'll be *native* apps

Comment: not exactly true.  You can use html in conjunction with titanium.

Answer (score 2):

If your target it's iOS or Android I suggest you should work with JavaScript and generate a native app. Also you can run any HTML code in a Titanium Web View component but I don't recommend it.

But if you want to reach other mobile OS you can also use Titanium but you'll need to create a web app.

Take a look at this article:
http://developer.appcelerator.com/blog/2011/09/titanium-sdk-for-mobile-web-beta-1.html
Mobile Web dev has been improved a lot since that article was posted. Check this http://docs.appcelerator.com for the latest documentation of what Titanium can do.

Comment: why don't you recommend running HTML in a titanium web view?

Answer (score 1):

It would be very niche book and not be useful for most people.  With Titanium you can:

1. write javascript code agains the Ti api, in which case at runtime native UI elements are invoked.
2. use a web view to load a normal website, which can contain an html5 app.  But then you are only using Titanium as a wrapper around a website.  There is some value in this approach, as you can use Titanium to invoke the device's hardware functions in response to actions in the web view.

It's probably better to do 1.  Why render a table in a web browser when you can just render a table?  Some people probably have used the approach in 2, but I'm guessing they are few and far between.

If you want to use html5 techs to develop a mobile app, you are better off with Sencha Touch 2.